# How to convert array value recieved from dropdown multiselect to string in angular 5

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular5, angular-arrays

I have used a material dropdown multiselect through which the users can select multiple data. when the data is being sent to the component the data is recieved in an array format which is not accepted by API to insert into database.
My view code:

```
      <mat-input-container>
    <input matInput type="number" formControlName="around" placeholder="Around" required >
    <p class="invalid-text" *ngIf="JifForm.controls.around.invalid &&
            (JifForm.controls.around.dirty || JifForm.controls.around.touched)">
      <span *ngIf="JifForm.controls.around.errors.required">Around is required.</span></p>
  </mat-input-container>

      <mat-form-field>
    <mat-select placeholder="Front Pass" formControlName="job_front_color" required multiple>
      <mat-option  value="pink">Pink</mat-option>
      <mat-option  value="black">Black</mat-option>
    </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>
```

it gives data in the following format :

```
job_deno: 12345
job_front_color:(2) ["pink", "black"]
```

Is there a way so that i get the value in `job_front_color` in string format too like `pink, black` so that the value can pass through the api as string

I pass data from the form to api through the following code:

```
  onSubmit(form) {
  //console.log('AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAa', form);
return this._http.post('http://localhost:8000/api/v1/jobInstructionForm ', form, {headers: this.headers}).subscribe(res => {
  this.flashMsg.flashMsg('success', 'added', 'JIF added');
  this._router.navigate( ['pages/jif'] );
} );
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Array.prototype.join()` - [Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)

In your case, what you want is `join(', ')`

```js
let arr = ["pink", "black"]
console.log(arr.join(', '));
```

---

**EDIT**

If you only want to send that string to your API, just do this:

```
onSubmit(form) {
  const stringOfColours = form.job_front_color.join(', );
  return this._http.post('http://localhost:8000/api/v1/jobInstructionForm ', stringOfColours, {
    headers: this.headers
  }).subscribe(res => {
    this.flashMsg.flashMsg('success', 'added', 'JIF added');
    this._router.navigate(['pages/jif']);
  });
}
```

Comment: well while that may do the work i still dont get how to send the value turned into string to my api. I have updated my question and added the code through which i have added my form values through api.

Comment: What's the current value of `form` ?

Comment: {
 job_deno: 12345,
 job_front_color:(2) ["pink", "black"]
}